# Fetching exact path of songs and building a URI

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I am using Exo Player in order to make an audio player for android. So far i am using this code and fetching the following info from my phone. Data, Name, Artist.

```
public void getMp3Songs() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                int songId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                arrayList.add(new Songs(songId, name, url));


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }

        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

The next thing i need is exact path of these tracks. 
For that purpose i am using this code.

```
private void initializePlayer(){
    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), new DefaultTrackSelector()
                , new DefaultLoadControl());

    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady);
    player.seekTo(currentWindow,playbackPosition);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
}

private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri,
            new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua"),
            new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
}
```

The problem is that when i start the player, nothing happens. Its just a blank player and its not playing anything. I think i am messing with the file paths here. Please help.

Comment: "The next thing i need is exact path of these tracks" -- you shouldn't, particularly since you cannot get one for everything. Use the `_ID` to generate a `Uri` for that content using `ContentUris.withAppendedId()`, and use that `Uri` with ExoPlayer.

Comment: I cant. I just don't know how to. I have searched everywhere. Can you provide  with some sample code.

Comment: `ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, songId)`

Comment: yes tried it too but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i found the solution if someone is in need he can use it. The problem was not in getting the address or building the `Uri`. It was in this particular section. `new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("ua")` Change this to this:

```
DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
            Util.getUserAgent(this, "idk"), new DefaultBandwidthMeter());
```

Now use this instance while returning `MediaSource`.